# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de escribir el valor de un atributo charset?

Tags: html

Me refiero, mayúsculas:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

o minúsculas:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Aunque tu pregunta se base en opiniones y no tenga una respuesta definitiva, este tema se trata muy bien en la siguiente discusión: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según las especificaciones se utilizaría mayúsculas:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Si quieres ampliar información: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629